# how to select multiple radio button in same while loop which is echoed from db

Tags: php, mysql, forms

guyz, i want to select radio button for each question.please help me to do that.now i can select only one radio button in a page...... check this link: https://i.stack.imgur.com/UI2vp.png

```
while($row= mysql_fetch_row($rs)){

echo "<form name=myfm method=post action=Quiz.php>";
echo "<table width=100%> <tr> <td width=30>&nbsp;<td> <table border=0>";
$n=$n+1;
echo "<tr><td><span class=style2>Question  ".  $n .": $row[2]</style>";
echo "<tr><td class=style8><input type=radio name='ques[$n][]' value=1>$row[3]";
echo "<tr><td class=style8> <input type=radio name='ques[$n][]' value=2>$row[4]";
echo "<tr><td class=style8><input type=radio name='ques[$n][]'  value=3>$row[5]";
echo "<tr><td class=style8><input type=radio name='ques[$n][]'  value=4>$row[6]";

}
```

How to fetch the data and store it to mydb...

```
    $query="select * from question";

    $rs=mysql_query("select * from question where testid=$tid",$cn) or die(mysql_error());

             if($submit=='Get Result')
            {
                $n=0;
                    while($row= mysql_fetch_row($rs)){

                        for($i=0;$i<count($_POST['ques']);$i++)
        {
            $ans=$_POST['ques'][$n][$i];
            echo $ans;
            $n=$n+1;
                            mysql_query("insert into useranswer(sessid, testid, ques, ans1,ans2,ans3,ans4,correctans,yourans) values ('".session_id()."',       $tid,'$row[2]','$row[3]','$row[4]','$row[5]', '$row[6]','$row[7]','$ans')") or die(mysql_error());}
                    }
  }
```

is this works???....

Comment: you should use `checkbox` for multiple selection.

Comment: i think siby means several sets of radio buttons.

Comment: You should use different *name* attributes for you different sets of radio buttons.
i.e. ques[1][], ques[2][].

Comment: please check image link

Comment: @Xardas:two dimentional array????

Answer (score 1):

Just replace `ques[]` with `ques[". $n ."][]` like this..

```
while($row= mysql_fetch_row($rs)){

echo "<form name=myfm method=post action=Quiz.php>";
echo "<table width=100%> <tr> <td width=30>&nbsp;<td> <table border=0>";
$n=$n+1;
echo "<tr><td><span class=style2>Question  ".  $n .": $row[2]</style>";
echo "<tr><td class=style8><input type=radio name='ques[".$n."][]' value=1>$row[3]";
echo "<tr><td class=style8> <input type=radio name='ques[". $n ."][]' value=2>$row[4]";
echo "<tr><td class=style8><input type=radio name='ques[". $n ."][]'  value=3>$row[5]";
echo "<tr><td class=style8><input type=radio name='ques[". $n ."][]'  value=4>$row[6]";

}
```

Comment: thankyou its working....but i need more reputation to accept answer...sorry for that...

Comment: Is this works??                                                                                              if($submit=='Get Result')
   {
    $n=0;
     while($row= mysql_fetch_row($rs)){
      $i=$_POST['$a'];
      for($i=0;$i<count($_POST['ques']);$i++)
  {
   $ans=$_POST['ques'][$n][$i];
   echo $ans;
   $n=$n+1;
       mysql_query("insert into useranswer(sessid, testid, ques, ans1,ans2,ans3,ans4,correctans,yourans) values ('".session_id()."',   $tid,'$row[2]','$row[3]','$row[4]','$row[5]', '$row[6]','$row[7]','$ans')") or die(mysql_error());}
     }

Comment: please tell me how to access the data which is send in the form...is the code above is correct...i want to store it in my db

Answer (score 0):

You have to name your radiobuttons for each set.

```
while($row=mysql_fetch_row($rs)) {
  echo "<form name=myfm method=post action=Quiz.php>";
  echo "<table width=100%> <tr> <td width=30>&nbsp;<td> <table border=0>";
  $n=$n+1;
  echo "<tr><td><span class=style2>Question  ".  $n .": $row[2]</style>";
  echo "<tr><td class=style8><input type=radio name='ques".$n."' value=1>$row[3]";
  echo "<tr><td class=style8> <input type=radio name='ques".$n."' value=2>$row[4]";
  echo "<tr><td class=style8><input type=radio name='ques".$n."'  value=3>$row[5]";
  echo "<tr><td class=style8><input type=radio name='ques".$n."'  value=4>$row[6]";

  echo "</table></table></form>"; //AND you should close your tags
}
```

Also, you should refrain from using mysql_functions, which are deprecated and removed in PHP7.

Comment: thsi one i have tried earlier.it works but.i want data from each question.

Comment: then instead you write one <form> before you start your loop and close it afterwards

Answer (score 0):

The mistake is that you are naming all your radio buttons with the same name. That makes all of them in one group. Name each group with three different names. Your problem is solved